# Maven 101 tutorial in spring.io Test fails

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

in this tutorial https://spring.io/guides/gs/maven/

I am to write the following code

```
1    package hello;
2
3    import hello.Greeter;
4   
5   import  org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.containsString;
6   import  org.junit.Assert.*;
7   
8   /**
9    * Created by mickeyp on 07/03/2017.
10   */
11  public class GreeterTest {
12    
13        private Greeter greeter = new Greeter();
14    
15        @Test
16        public void greeterSaysHello() {
17            assertThat(greeter.sayHello(), containsString("Hello"));
18        }
19    }
20
```

The compile fails with :

> - package org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers does not exist ( 5, 34)
> - package org.junit.Assert doesn't exist           ( 6, 1 )
> - cannot resolve symbol @Test                      ( 15,4 )

Bellow is the dependency part of the pom.xml file

> ```
> <dependencies>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
>         <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
>         <version>2.2</version>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>junit</groupId>
>         <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
>         <version>4.12</version>
>         <scope>test</scope>
>     </dependency>
>
> </dependencies>
> ```

I see in intellJ that gs-maven has my Dependencies (specifically junit.4.12) correctly.

I am new to java, very veteran C# developer

how do i fix this?

Comment: In the tutorials is mentioned that you have to add junit as dependency. Apart from that please post the pom file ...

Comment: Try to reimport from pom.xml to ensure that IntelliJ IDEA has added all the dependencies correctly. Otherwise, please provide the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It finally works, only took a few hours (better part of 2 days, on and off)

1. func fact, intelliJ sometimes requires a cache restart
   File|Invalidate cache / Restart
2. the location of GreeterTest is what the dependency in the pom.xml meant

   ```
   <scope>test</scope>
   ```

this is defined in the maven structure which means

> ```
> src/main/java/--> java classes
>   src/test/---> test classes
> ```

also
when creating the test directory in the src/test , you need to

> right click the directory | Mark directory as ==> test directory

also

if you have a pom file
FILE| open .. find the pom.xml file and click on it, and it will import the project, i still needed to invalidate the caches (see above) , but it works
now

bwaaa that was not as simple as I expected